# How to put a box around something in GIMP?

Tags: software-recommendation, gimp, design

This is a very simply question, but one that I have been struggling to find an answer to: How can I put a box outline around something in GIMP? So that you can easily circle (but with a rectangle or square and not a circle) something in an image that you want to point out to someone. Or is there a better tool which would easily allow it without lots of manual drawing if it cannot easily be done in GIMP? When on Windows I would use Paint for this as I could not find an option in GIMP, but now in Ubuntu I can't find anything else to do it in.

Comment: Point 1: This is about GIMP, not Ubuntu. Point 2: You can easily do this(in pretty much ANY image editor) with the rectangle tool.

Comment: This question is not off-topic. Per the help center: "What topics can I ask about here?... Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.". If you look through the [tag:gimp] tag there are other question similar to this one as well.

Comment: @HeatherBrown: As GIMP runs on Ubuntu, and this is really only impacting me because I am on Ubuntu, I would say that it is on-topic. With the rectangle tool I am able to create a rectangle or square of a perticular colour, however how do you make an outline around something and not just fill?

Comment: @Tim I don't think [graphicdesign.se] would like this question. Their help center states: "What topics should I avoid asking about?... Simple "How to" questions — please search your application's help files first, and do a Google search before posting a question".

Comment: @HeatherBrown: Anyway, if you think it such an easy question, why don't you just post the answer?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I was away from Ubuntu and did not have GIMP at my disposal to take a screenshot. Answer with screen shot now updated.

Comment: It is off topic, it should have gone to the gimp category of the graphic design site: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gimp

Comment: @AlexFitzpatrick: It may have done fine.

Comment: However as @Seth said, it is not off-topic here as said in the help centre.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Select the area you would like to outline with the rectangle select tool.
[image]

go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Stroke Selection</kbd>.

[image]

You will get a dialogue. Choosing <kbd>Solid Line</kbd> will create an outline using the currently selected foreground color. Choosing <kbd>Stroke with a Paint Tool</kbd> will give you more creativity.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Create new layer.
Rectangle select for outer wall of rectangle.
Bucket fill that rectangle or paste a texture if you want to use a texture for your outline.
Edit shrink selection by the width you want for your rectangle.
Cut.
Right click on the layer and merge the layer down.

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?&q=create+rectangle+gimp

Comment: I'd border the selection and just fill it in a new layer.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple solution:

1. Select the Pencil tool

   [image]
2. Click on your image

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and hold and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hold for the steps below
4. Move your mouse and click
5. Move and click again to complete your rectangle

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

You have answers for gimp, but 
I also find gimp a bit hard work for this sort of thing. I don't have windows so I don't know what its Paint is like, but I can recommend the very simple and old `xpaint`, the even simpler gnome version `gpaint`, or my favourite for over 10 years (and more sophisticated), `xfig`, all in ubuntu.

Comment: I also liked mtpaint or pinta for this kind of job

Answer (score 2):

A **GIMP** Alternate:

## A simple tool for drawing rectangles and ellipses on pictures is already included in Ubuntu

## LibreOffice:Draw

1. Open the image in LibreOffice Draw. You can do this by first opening
   Draw and then opening the image in it. Or you can right click on the
   image and choose Open with > Other Applications > Show other
   applications.
2. Look for **Basic Shapes** in the left hand tool bar and click the
   down arrow next to it. See **Step 2** in the picture below:

[image]

3. Select **Frame** or **Ring** shape. You can reduce the width of the
   ring and squish to to an ellipse if you want.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Select Filters > Render > Gfig... From there you can draw boxes and other shapes boxes in various styles.

Answer (score 1):

A different tool that I use a lot for this purpose is Flameshot. It is very handy when you want to take a screenshot of something, then mark, annotate, blur, point to stuff, etc.

[image: Flameshot]

Basically, we use `Right-Click` to pick colors, and `Ctrl+Mouse_Wheel` to increase and decrease stroke width. See README on the repo for more detailed info.

https://github.com/flameshot-org